# How to make a timer work in between two methods

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a bot to make some mouse click and make some auto typing. My mouse movements are working properly by my typing is not working between them.

I am trying to make a mouse click in my desired position then type some text from text box and then click in another window position. First click event fires properly then the types only one word and then fires 2nd mouse click. After that it types the remaining. Such as if I type "Hello World" then it makes a mouse click in my desired position and types"H" then click on 2nd mouse position and at last types "ello World". I am still a newbie in c#.

```
private void tyPer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           Random randomnum = new Random();
           tyPer.Enabled = false;
           tyPer.Interval = randomnum.Next(125, 225);
           if (count < textBox1.Text.Length)
           {
             SendKeys.Send(textBox1.Text.Substring(count++, 1));
             tyPer.Enabled = true;
           }
           else 
           {
           count = 0;
           }
        }

private void cp_process()
        {            
            mouse_move_1();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            tyPer.Enabled = true;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            mouse_move_2();
        }

private void btnST_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int nocp = Convert.ToInt16(NOCPtxtBox.Text);
            int td = Convert.ToInt16(TDtxtBox.Text);
            for (int i = 1; i <= nocp; i++)
            {                
                cp_process();                
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(td*1000);
            }
        }

private void mouse_move_1()
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt16(CPtextBox_X.Text);
            int y = Convert.ToInt16(CPtextBox_Y.Text);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
private void mouse_move_2()
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt16(CPtextBox_X.Text);
            int y = Convert.ToInt16(CPtextBox_Y.Text);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
```

First Mouse click fires in my desired position but then the typer is not working properly. What should I do???

Comment: Why are you using a timer?  Why don't you call the method directly after moving the mouse?

Comment: timer types the text in different interval...if I directly call the method it does not type the whole thing because of the loop...only the first letter

Comment: Using a timer is the correct approach.  But it can't do its job when you make the UI thread go catatonic for 20 seconds.  You have to get rid of your old bad code.  Delete the Sleep() calls.  And avoid SendKeys, you can simply update the Text property directly.

Comment: Those Sleep codes are after the clicks are performed and SendKeys are to send values to external widow. But tried your suggestion. Not Working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - Random. Random constructor should be used ONLY once in the whole application. You call it in every timer tick. This will make the random to give you same results. You need to have only one instance of Random in your application and use it.

Next, don't use Sleep. Sleep makes the whole thread to go to sleep :) It means that it won't be able to do anything. Even GUI operations. You application will freeze. You should do it in another thread. I would do it like that: (treat it more like a sketch, not a working solution, because I write it from head).

```
async Task MoveMouse(Point pt)
{
    //magically move mouse to point - ONLY MOVE it
}

async Task TypeCharacter(char ch)
{
    //magically type a character - only type it
}

async Task PrintToTextBox(string text)
{
    foreach(var ch in text)
    {
       await TypeCharacter(ch);
       Task.Wait(randomizer.Next(125, 225));
    }
}

void Start()
{
   Task.Run(async () => await DoWork());
   //or maybe simple: Task.Run(() => DoWork());
   //it really depends on your context, you can do a deadlock
}

async Task DoWork()
{
    for(...)
    {
       await MouseMove(pt);
       Task.Wait(waitMs); //wait for several miliseconds or TimeSpan

       await PrintToTextBox(textToPrint);
       Task.Wait(waitAfterPrintingMs);
       await MouseMove(pt2);
       //...
    }
}
```

I used here async and await. You can read about them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ but it maybe hard to understand at first.

Instead of async/await you can use old good Threads.

Comment: Thanks for your help... it was really a skeleton for my project. :)